# Can I charge my clients for debugging the code I have developed for them?

Tags: payment

I charge my clients on an hourly basis, some times they came back with an error or bug in code requesting me to resolve it. It takes time, sometimes reaching 2-3 hours. Most clients think it should not be charged as it was my fault and I should fix it for free. Is that so? It's almost impossible to code 100% error free.

Comment: I'm not sure that this question should be on SO ? Isn't there a stack exchange site dedicated to these question ? Can anyone confirm this ?

Comment: How is this question relevant here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about business pricing and not about coding s defined in the faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it depends. Is the product that you sold working as described in the contract ? If not, well you can't decently ask for more money since you didn't do your job in the first place. You should test your software and do debug for free. It is true that no software is bug free, but it isn't the customer's fault and, as long as you didn't explicitly state that debugging had a cost, well I think it isn't okay to charge for it. (be sure to not let them add features pretending it's a bug, though) !

Comment: May i know who downvoted this ? And why ? No explanation ? What did i do wrong ?

Comment: Your answer is really helpful, sorry I am not able to upvote it because it needs more than 15 rep and I didn't use StackOverflow that much. I don't get why someone has downvoted it.

Comment: If you think it does help, i think you can mark it as "answers the question". If it didn't answer your question please let me know what you want precisions about :-)

Comment: Thank you :-) Glad I could help !

Comment: I didn't downvote you but whomever did probably did so because you answered an obviously off topic question. That is generally frowned upon.